# React for loops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

I'm learning JavaScript / React. I'm trying to create a simple for loop for the tic-tac-toe example on the react website but so far its been problematic. Oddly, theres several map examples but no for loop examples.

Anyway, for the following:

```
function Row(props){
  function renderSquare (i) {
    return <Square key={i} value={props.squares[i]} onClick={() => props.onClick(i)} />;
  }
  const columns = 3;
  let ss = [];
  for(var a = 0, i = props.counter * columns; a < 3; a++, i++){
    //Test Code
  }
  return (
    <div className="board-row">
      {ss}
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I replace "Test Code", this works

```
ss.push(renderSquare(i));
```

But this fails

```
ss.push(<Square key={i} value={props.squares[i]} onClick={() => props.onClick(i)}/>);
```

The second option fails since its not creating "separate" onClick elements. How can I make the failing example work?

---

Update #1

### [Sample](https://codepen.io/TriStarGod/pen/mRpVwV?editors=0111)

Update #2
I changed the var to let as recommended by @Matthias247 and it now works :D

```
function Row(props){
  function renderSquare (i) {
    return <Square key={i} value={props.squares[i]} onClick={() => props.onClick(i)} />;
  }
  const columns = 3;
  let ss = [];
  for(let a = 0, i = props.counter * columns; a < columns; a++, i++){
    ss.push(<Square key={i} value={props.squares[i]} onClick={() => props.onClick(i)}/>);
    //ss.push(renderSquare(i));
    //console.log(i);
  }
  return (
    <div className="board-row">
      {ss}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you capture `i` into the element and the `onClick` closure. You change `i` during the for loop, but in the end it's the same for all inserted elements -> `props.counter + 3`.

To fix it you need to create a unique instance of all captured values for each element. This is exactly what you do with the `renderSquare` method which creates a new instance of `i` inside the function body, which is now captured by the element.

Edit:

Using a `let` binding, which creates a fresh instance of the variable per iteration, also works:

```
for (let a = 0, i = props.counter; a < 3; a++, i++) {
    ss.push(<Square key={i} value={props.squares[i]} onClick={() => props.onClick(i)}/>);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, let doesn't work. I'll try to post my sample.

Comment: I understand the theory but unsure how to implement it.

Comment: it doesn't work because you haven't moved i into the loop and made it a `let` binding. Which means you still only had a single instance of the `i` object and a fresh object per iteration. You only changed `a` to a let binding.
If you use exactly the code I posted then it works.

Comment: Wow, thanks. First time var vs let made a difference.